# Unable to connect to Geckodriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I'm trying to run the example scirpt of Selenium with Ruby on Rails. I've to run it with a proxy. Here's my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

# require your gems as usual
require "selenium-webdriver"

Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = "/home/marc/Documents/firefox/firefox"
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
proxy = Selenium::WebDriver::Proxy.new(:http => nil)
profile.proxy = proxy
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
driver.navigate.to "http://google.com"

element = driver.find_element(:name, 'q')
element.send_keys "Hello WebDriver!"
element.submit

puts driver.title

driver.quit
```

I got the following error:

```
/home/marc/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.0.beta3.1/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:115:in `connect_until_stable': unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver 127.0.0.1:4445 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

Can someone help me...? I'm trying since hours and can't find the problem... Really don't know what to do.

Environment:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS,
 Firefox 45.0,
 rbenv 2.3.1

Other question: Someone knows some example for Selenium + Ruby on Rails?  I can't find really good stuff... the documentation is really poor :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have `selenium-webdriver-3.0.0.beta3.1` which is only for Firefox 48 and later (and not yet properly working).
Fallback to `selenium-webdriver` version [`2.53.4`](https://rubygems.org/gems/selenium-webdriver/versions/2.53.4) and try again.

Comment: Thanks, i got the solution yesterday by myself. But it was exactly my problem, so you were 100 % right.

Comment: thanks.  i was trying to downgrade firefox and install gecko drivers and it didnt work.  i just added "gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.53.4'" and ran bundle update selenium-webdriver, and it works again.

Comment: the problem is that newer versions of selenium (> 3.0) are not compatible with the older versions of Firefox (< 48).

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to DarKy's solution with selenium version downgrade:

- In the terminal change directory path to the directory where gem was installed
- Run `gem uninstall selenium-webdriver`
- Run `gem install selenium-webdriver -v 2.53.4`

Answer (score 1):

- ruby: ruby 2.3.3p222
- selenium-webdriver: selenium-webdriver (3.7.0)
- Firefox : V57

---

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.driver_path = "‪C:\\Users\\Desktop\\geckodriver.exe"
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(accept_insecure_certs: true)
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, desired_capabilities: capabilities
driver.navigate.to "https://google.com"
```