# Ruby Watir unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, watir, geckodriver

I'm trying to upgrade Firefox, from a version before whatever disaster has befallen the driver situation, to the most recent version for macOS (which seems to be 50.1.0). I upgraded to the latest selenium-webdriver (3.0.5) and watir (6.1.0, formerly watir-webdriver).

I downloaded the latest geckodriver (0.13.0), added it to `usr/bin/local` and made it executable, which stopped the `Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver` errors. However ...

```
$ irb
2.3.1 :001 > require 'watir'
2.3.1 :002 > b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to Mozilla geckodriver 127.0.0.1:4444
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:130:in `connect_until_stable'
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:74:in `block in start'
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_lock.rb:41:in `locked'
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:71:in `start'
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:32:in `initialize'
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `new'
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.0.5/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:82:in `for'
    from /path/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/watir-6.1.0/lib/watir/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I can't find any documentation about what else I can do at this point. Chrome works just fine, but I require Firefox. Since the Firefox driver 'just worked' before, I'm not sure what if any tools I have for diagnosis. (The Watir/Watir-Webdriver documentation still says Firefox just works.) Any hints would be much appreciated...

[The marked duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699531/unable-to-connect-to-geckodriver) is perhaps a duplicate error, but the accepted answer is to roll back the interlocking technologies' versions. That is the literal opposite of what I was attempting to accomplish.

Also, I was (and am) specifically looking for documentation and/or diagnostic tools that detail or uncover which versions of watir, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver and Firefox (or some subset thereof) play nicely together.

Comment: Add it in Ruby23/bin

Comment: @Gopal I moved geckodriver to `/path/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/` and I get the same error message. So it must be finding it there, but the issue remains...

Comment: What about Chrome? Chrome is working fine?

Comment: @Gopal Chrome works.

Comment: Place your Chrome driver in this path and check whether it works or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to Geckodriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39699531/unable-to-connect-to-geckodriver)

Comment: @kenorb The accepted answer on the linked question is directly opposite what I am asking for. Please see my updates.